# parseInt(x,10) causing max callstack/too much recursion error

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion

I have a simple JS function that updates a hidden textbox based on 2 input values.

Before I update the hidden text box, I use the the parseInt(x,10) to validate that input is numeric, if not I set the value to 0.

Why is this causing a too much recursion error?

```
  $(function () {
        $("#payment-form").on("submit",function (e) {

            var xDollars = $("#dollars").val();
            var xCents = $("#cents").val();
            //collect our form dollar and cents values, set to 0 if not int
            if (parseInt(xDollars, 10) == "NaN") {
                $("#dollars").val("0");
            }
            if (parseInt(xCents, 10) == "NaN") {
                $("#cents").val("00");
            }

            //join dollars and cents and submit transaction amount
            $("#TransactionAmount").val(xDollars + "." + xCents);
            $("#payment-form").submit();
            return true;
        });
    });
```

Comment: Your error has nothing to do with `parseInt()`, it's because you're raising the event you're trapping within the event handler, for some odd reason. Why are you calling `submit()` again?

Comment: I'm interested in knowing why someone voted to close this? I think this was a pretty legitimate question.

Comment: Just from a UI perspective.. if either of the values are non-numeric, wouldn't you want to cancel the submission request and display a form error?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, there is more code to this. The UI actually forces numeric. This was an additional fall back and NULL value support.  It's also re-validated on the backend.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not `parseInt()` that's causing your problem, it's this:

```
        $("#payment-form").submit();
```

You're triggering the "submit" action from inside the "submit" handler.

If you just return `true` if validation succeeds, the form should submit normally.

Answer (score 2):

That's because jQuery does not differentiate whether you are submitting a form via a `submit` event or via `.submit()` method. Therefore, if you use jQuery's `$.submit()`, it will fire a `submit` event manually.

Use vanilla-js instead. According to [Form submission algorithm](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#form-submission-algorithm), that event won't be fired if you use `.submit()`:

> If the *submitted from [`submit()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-form-submit) method* flag is not set, then
>   [fire a simple event](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#fire-a-simple-event) that bubbles and is cancelable named
>   `submit`, at *form*. If the event's default action is prevented (i.e.
>   if the event is canceled) then abort these steps. Otherwise, continue
>   (effectively the default action is to perform the submission).

Therefore, this wouldn't be problematic:

```
document.getElementById('payment-form').submit();
```

But in this case you can just remove `$("#payment-form").submit();`. If you don't cancel the event, the form should be submitted automatically.